# How to send unique props to similar Parents?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, use-state

I currently made a custom component that acts similar to a carousel called **Scrollbar**. When I select a specific item it dynamically loads the information and displays a content div that has information on the item such as id, name, thumbnail-Image, etc..

The problem I am trying to solve is that I want to display multiple **Scrollbars** and only have one content div active at a time. The issue is that each Scrollbar has their own content div. I need a way to communicate which one is active.

I'm thinking possibly I need another component lets call it **Home** that displays multiple **Scrollbars** and onClick, it sets the current one Active and the rest inActive. All the **Scrollbars** should still be displaying however, one dynamic content div will appear below the active **Scrollbar**.

This sounds like I need to send one **Scrollbar's** prop `isActive = true` and the others `isActive = false`. I am unsure how to achieve this.

Here are short versions of my components:

**Scrollbar.js**

```
const Scrollbar = ({category, isActive }) => {


return (  
     <div className="scrollbar">
                <h2>{category}</h2>
                <div className="item-wrapper" style={{maxWidth: `${scrollbarWidth}px`}}>
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   .
                    //Handles Navigating the Scrollbar Left and Right
                    <SlideButton  type="prev" onClick={handlePrev}/>
                    <SlideButton  type="next" onClick={handleNext}/>
                </div>
                //Dynamic Content gets shown here when user clicks on an item & Scrollbar (tbd)
                {isActive && currentCard && <Content activeCard={currentCard} clickFunc={handleCardChange}  /> }
                
     </div>
    );
}
 
export default Scrollbar;
```

**Home.js**

```
const Home = () => {

       
        return ( 
            
            <div className="home">
                <Scrollbar key="0" category="Scroll 1" activeBar={null} />,
                <Scrollbar key="1" category="Scroll 2" activeBar={null} />
            </div>
        );
    
}
 
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Home` component should hold the id of who is the `activeBar` with `useState`. It should pass `setActiveBar` to each `Scrollbar`.

```
const Home = () => {
  const [activeBar, setActiveBar] = useState(0)
       
  return ( 
    <div className="home">
        <Scrollbar 
          key="0"
          id="0"
          category="Scroll 1" 
          activeBar={activeBar} 
          setActiveBar={setActiveBar}
          />,
        <Scrollbar 
          key="1"
          id="1"
          category="Scroll 2" 
          activeBar={activeBar} 
          setActiveBar={setActiveBar}
          />
    </div>
  );   
}
```

The `Scrollbar` component should check if it's `id` is identical to `activeBar`, and set `isActive` accordingly. It should also set itself to be the `activeBar` when clicked.

```
const Scrollbar = ({category, id, activeBar, onClick }) => {
  const isActive = activeBar === id;

  return (  
    <div 
      onClick={() => setActiveBar(id)}
      className="scrollbar"
      >
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and explanation, it works great and is easy to understand and learn from!